# Compass Crashing Anytime Sass (SCSS) File Compiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, sass, compass-sass

I just upgraded to Mac OSX Mavericks and then made all of the updates in the App Store and now I can't compile my SCSS files! I am using CodeKit with Compass and am running Mac OSX 10.9. Here is the error CodeKit is spitting out at me:

```
Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project: 

/Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/oilypng/lib/oily_png/oily_png.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

If you'd like to see the full code kit error, here it is: http://pastebin.com/740UMt5R

If you'd like to see the full User Diagnostic report, here it is: http://pastebin.com/vK0CjEcL

Answer (score 0):

Add these 2 lines to the “config.rb" without having to make any other changes at all to the SCSS files:

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated CodeKit to version 1.9 and everything works now. I do, however, think that Eric's solution would probably work too.